# How to use Winston Logger in NestJS separate module that doesn't use Classes

Tags: nestjs, winston

I've tried a few different ways of doing this.

I can't set Winston as the default logger for NestJS at the moment because it complains about "getTimestamp" function not being in the instance.

So - for controllers in NestJS - I have used dependency injection - which works fine for the api ( REST endpoints ).

The problem is that I have moved away from OOP - so all of my libraries are written in typescript as functions. Not pure functions but better than an OOP approach ( many less bugs! )

My question is - how do I get access to the main winston logger within my libraries that don't have classes.

I am using the library nest-winston.

Comment: How are you using Nest without the use of classes? That's what the entire dependency injection system (for the most part) is built around

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  Nest is only used for the APIs.  the API's call the rest of my functionality which is in libraries that has a more functional programming approach.

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing your approach. Without dependency injection, you'd have to either set up a winston instance that can be globally accessed, pass the winston instance to each function, or set up a winston instance in each method. None of those really seem appealing to me, but without DI there won't be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks @JayMcDoniel - Yes I wasn't overly keen on the OOP to start with.  I get much faster, more bug-free code since moving to a more functional programming approach.  I only wanted to use NESTJS for quick REST APIs

Comment: Then you're probably better off using Express. Nest very heavily lends itself to OOP code with classes and other object oriented principles.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

> create the logger outside of the application lifecycle, using the createLogger function, and pass it to NestFactory.create ([`nest-winston` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-winston#use-as-the-main-nest-logger-also-for-bootstrapping))

You can have a separate file that creates the logging instance, then import that into your modules/libraries as well as import it into your `main.ts`

```js
// src/logger/index.ts
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';

export const myLogger = WinstonModule.createLogger({
  // options (same as WinstonModule.forRoot() options)
})
```

```js
// src/myLib/index.ts
import { myLogger } from '@/logger' // I like using aliases

export const myLib = () => {
  // ...
  myLogger.log('Yay')
}
```

```js
// src/main.ts
import { myLogger } from '@/logger' 
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: myLogger
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: For me this recipe didn't work. Nest logs dissapear in console and Nestjs app falls silently withot any error.